# Can I use certificates from S3 in ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a question about this: can I save certificates in an S3 bucket and then use them in an ingress controller for my applications? I cannot find information about this.

May with annotations in ingress?

I'll try this on an EKS cluster

Thanks